# Suprimindo valor ao chamar função Javascript

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo não passa um valor para y  mas mesmo assim o código funciona, alguém sabe como funciona?

Gostaria de aprender mais sobre, alguém sabe o nome desta característica do javascript?

```js
function base(x) {
  return function produto(y) {
    return x * y;
  }
}

var f = base(2);
var g = base(-1);

console.log(f(2) + g(-1)); // 5
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Esse conceito é o que se chama *high-order-function*. Ou seja uma função que retorna outra, configurada para um dado processo.

Programar dessa maneira integra-se na filosofia de *functional programming*, porque nesse caso a função `base` é pura e retorna sempre uma função, é portanto um instrumento do fluxo da aplicação.

Nesse caso quando invocas a função base recebes uma função high-order que recebe um argumento e multiplica pelo que já foi pré-configurado.

Nesse caso podias até ter nomes mais claros como:

```js
function base(x){
    return function produto(y){
           return x * y;
    }
}

var vezesDois = base(2);
var inverterSinal = base(-1);

console.log(vezesDois(7)); // 14
console.log(inverterSinal(435)); // -435
```